# If date is less than a week ago conditional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a conditional where if `@challenge.deadline` (which is a `Date`) is within the last week (i.e. the last 7 days), then do *x*, else do *y*.

I tried:

```
if @challenge.deadline < 1.week.ago #2017-03-03 01:52:13 -0500
if @challenge.deadline < 7.days.ago.to_date #2017-03-03
if @challenge.deadline < Date.current-7.days #2017-03-03
# All these come up false since I guess it sees 06 as more than 03, but I want the conditional to be based on date such as 06 is less than 7 days ago and therefore should be true
```

In this example `@challenge.deadline` equals `2017-03-06`

Comment: is your deadline a Date object?

Comment: _"I guess it sees 06 as more than 03 ..."_ – well, yes. Why do you expect 2017-03-06 to be _smaller_ than 2017-03-03?

Comment: Exactly, that's how it sees it @Stefan. The question is how can I get it to not see it like that. In other words, how can I trigger the conditional when `@challenge.deadline` is a date that has happened within the last 7 days?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com so instead of "before 7 days ago" you want "between 7 days ago and today"?

Comment: `@challenge.deadline < 1.week.ago` checks the date is before 1 week ago. In this case you may have to interchange your X and Y blocks. Or change you condition to `@challenge.deadline > 1.week.ago`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> how can I trigger the conditional when `@challenge.deadline` is a date that has happened within the last 7 days?

*"within the last 7 days"* describes a range from:

```
Date.current - 7 #=> Fri, 03 Mar 2017
```

to:

```
Date.current     #=> Fri, 10 Mar 2017
```

To check whether `@challenge.deadline` lies within these bounds, you can use [`between?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F):

```
today = Date.current
if @challenge.deadline.between?(today - 7, today)
  # within last 7 days
else
  # either before of after
end
```

Instead of `today - 7`, you can also use `today - 7.days` or `today - 1.week`.

Or, to use an actual range:

```
today = Date.current
last_week = (today - 7)..today

if last_week.cover?(@challenge.deadline)
  # ...
else
  # ...
end
```

If you need this often, you could also consider patching `Date`:

```
class Date
  def within_last?(duration, date = Date.current)
    between?(date - duration, date)
  end
end
```

and check it via:

```
if @challenge.deadline.within_last?(1.week)
  # ...
else
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if @challenge.deadline.to_date < 1.week.ago.to_date
    do X
else
    do Y
end
```

Comment: Ok, try <= in condition

Comment: You should look on values in you console, for me that condition is false because `@challenge.deadline` in 6th Mar and 1.week.ago is 3d Mar, and 6 > 3

Comment: Exactly. That's my problem.

Comment: So you should change `<=` to `>=` and it'll solve your problem